# Sequelize case-sensitive queries

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize and want to know, how to send case-sensitive queries to my DB.

I have table `users` with a column `Login`.

And when I send request, `(data.Login = '***0xwraith***')`, sequelize finds me user with login `0xWraith`. But I want the logins `0xWraith` and `0xwraith` be distinct and separate.

This is the code I use:

```
let db_user = await db.users.findOne({
            where: {
                Login: data.login
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you add the info what DB you are using?  Because case sensitivity is depending on the DB rather than Sequelize.

Comment: Mysql phpmyadmin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL's string comparison is case insensitive by default.

If you would like to have case sensitive query just for this query, you can add BINARY keyword before the comparison to enable it.

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE BINARY(`Login`) = '0xWraith';
```

You can write the query in Sequelize as following.

```
db.users.findOne({
    where: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('BINARY', sequelize.col('Login')), data.login)
})
```

If you want to enable the case sensitivity as a table level, read more about it here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case-sensitivity.html.